# attributes with vertex shader in three.js produces out of range vertices error

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, three.js, webgl

I've been trying to learn the use of shaders with three.js using [this link](https://aerotwist.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-shaders-part-1/), which is unfortunately a little out of date, and in trying to update the code I got this far:

```
<script id="vshader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    attribute float displacement;

    varying vec3 vNormal;

    void main() {
        vNormal = normal;

        vec3 newPosition = position + normal * vec3(displacement);

        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(newPosition, 1.0);
    }
</script>
<script id="fshader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    varying vec3 vNormal;

    void main() {
        vec3 light = vec3(0.5, 0.2, 1.0);

        light = normalize(light);

        float dprod = max(0.0, dot(vNormal, light));
        gl_FragColor = vec4(dprod, dprod, dprod, 1.0);
    }
</script>

var shaderProperties = {
    vertexShader: document.getElementById("vshader").textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById("fshader").textContent
};

var shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(shaderProperties);
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(3, 12, 12);
var bufgeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(geometry);

var verts = geometry.vertices;
var displacement = new Float32Array(verts);

for (var v = 0; v < verts.length; v++) {
    displacement[v] = Math.random() * 3;
}
bufgeometry.addAttribute("displacement", new THREE.BufferAttribute(displacement, 1));

var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(bufgeometry, shaderMaterial);
scene.add(sphere);
```

But this produces the following error:

GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 2

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: First thing I see is you are not sending the displacement attribute to the ShaderMaterial. http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/ShaderMaterial

Comment: Here is a simple example of displacement, though it uses a uniform instead. http://blog.2pha.com/demos/threejs/shaders/perlin_noise_3d_vertex.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the problem was with the latest release of three.js which requires attributes to be attached to buffer geometry using BufferGeometry.addAttribute(). I was trying to do something like that, but incorrectly.

[This example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_custom_attributes) was very helpful, the changes I made look like this:

```
var shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(shaderProperties);
var geometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(3, 90, 90);
var displacement = new Float32Array(geometry.attributes.position.count);

for (var v = 0; v < displacement.length; v++) {
    displacement[v] = Math.random() * 2;
}

geometry.addAttribute("displacement", new THREE.BufferAttribute(displacement, 1));
```

Using SphereBufferGeometry to skip the step of creating a SphereGeometry and then a BufferGeometry from that. And using the count of position attributes on the buffer geometry instead of the length of the array of vertices on the sphere geometry.

[Here it is](http://jsbin.com/juqatafuqi/edit?html,js,output) in action.